How to prefetch and display animated image using Fresco?
I need to display an animated image from the network. Since animated images may take long to load I want to display another image (lightweigh and static), from the network as well, in it's place like a placeholder. Once the animated image is prefetched I want to replace the static image with the new animated image.
Right now I'm loading the static image with simpleDraweeView.setImageUriOrGone(staticImagePath) and inmediatly I'm prefetching the animated image like this:
val imageRequest = ImageRequest.fromUri(animatedImagePath)
val imagePipeline = Fresco.getImagePipeline()
val dataSource: DataSource<Void> = imagePipeline.prefetchToDiskCache(imageRequest, context)

Normally I would show the animated image like this:
val controller = Fresco.newDraweeControllerBuilder()
    .setUri(uri)
    .setAutoPlayAnimations(true)
    . // other setters
    .build();
simpleDraweeView.setController(controller);

But from my testing, doing this without prefetching simply replaces the static image right away, leaving a blank space while loading the animated image.
I know I can subscribe to the dataSource and listen to onNewResultImpl() like here but then what can I do to display the animated image? The DataSource that prefetch gives does not have a ClosableReference and I don't know how to access the prefetched image
